# Iterate over days of year to make a list/graph

Tags: plotting, date-and-time

How do I make a graph of a function which takes a date as input, over a full year?

**[Edit]** To clarify, I have an existing function, say `f`, which takes a date as input and returns a value between 0 and 90. I want to plot this function over the year 2016, so plot the value for every day in 2016.

**My try**

I can reduce this question to making a list like

```
Table[
 {d, f[d]},
 {d, DateObject[{2016, 1, 1}], DateObject[{2016, 12, 31}]}
 ]
```

and then doing `ListPlot` or something, but obviously I need to give Mathematica at least the step size (one day) and find a way to add a day to a date in such an iteration.

Maybe `DateRange` is an idea to make a list of dates of a year, but not sure how I would attach my function to that properly.

PS I'm on Mathematica 11.0

**[Edit]** As per request, my own function is a little big too put here, but for example function

```
g[d_] := (
  DateValue[d, "Month"] + DateValue[d, "Day"]
  )
```

Will do, I guess.

Comment: what do you want your graph to look like?

Comment: I'm guessing you want date on x axis? what do you want on y axis?

Comment: @ConorCosnett I just want to plot my function, yes date on x axis and function value on y axis. That's why I thought of using a list (matrix actually), I'll try to make use of the function in your answer, now!

Comment: So you want your function to take a date as an input? what do you want as your functions output?

Comment: what do you want your function to do ? @PHPirate

Comment: @ConorCosnett (sorry for the delay) No sorry I think you misinterpreted the question, I'm asking how to make a graph of a function which takes a date as input, I already have a (big) function which works fine, it returns a value between 0 and 90 given a date. I'll try to clarify the question, hope it helps

Comment: Paste your function and I will try and graph it @PHPirate

Comment: @Conor Are you sure? Working with a test function will not matter for sure?

Comment: @ConorCosnett Edited question for example function

Comment: I fixed my function now @PHPirate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### solution with `DateListPlot`

```
Clear[f,g]
f = Function[x, DateObject[{2016, 1, 1}] + Quantity[(x-1), "Days"]]
g[d_] := (DateValue[d, "Month"] + DateValue[d, "Day"])
listOfDates = Table[{f[d], g[f[d]]}, {d, 1, 365}];

DateListPlot[listOfDates]
```

[image]

---

> ```
> ListPlot[Table[g[f[d]], {d, 1, 365}]]
> ```

[image]

---

Here is a function which you give 1 to return the first day 1 in 2016 ect.

use `Quantity`

```
f = Function[x, DateObject[{2016, 1, 1}] + Quantity[(x-1), "Days"]]

Table[{f[d], g[f[d]]}, {d, 1, 365}]
```

[image]

---

Comment: For me, the addition of dates doesn't work... I get back for `f[3]` the date plus days, so `3 + DateObject[{2015, 12, 31}]` (Oh, I'm on MMa 11, if that is relevant)

Comment: @PHPirate Could you describe the output of your function?

Comment: See comment on the question, as far as I understand if your function (the first one) worked, I could do something like (`g`is my function) `Table[{f[d], g[f[d]]}, {d, 1, 365}]`

Comment: Thanks a lot, your function works now! I get indeed the table I wanted! I see it's just a little thing, but do you know why moving the `x-` in the `Quantity[]` fixes it? Oh, and for some reason `ListPlot` won't plot the table yet, but I'll try to find something (PS you can remove the second part of your answer)

Comment: Oh I just saw it, yes that works, but is there a possibility to put some real dates on the x-axis instead of day of year? Just for the fancy looks... Maybe the month?

Comment: Just googled for that, I think it should be fixed with using `DateListPlot`? Anyway, +1 for helping me learn that adding a number to a date doesn't work, but adding a quantity does!

Comment: @PHPirate I included `DateListPlot` now